# Why does my I2C write get NAK'd?

Tags: pic, i2c, timing, reverse-engineering

I am trying to interface to an existing device, for which I do not have documentation.  The device exposes a 5v I<sup>2</sup>C interface with several IC's on the bus.  I have used a logic analyzer to capture the traffic, and do not understand why my writes are not being accepted.

Working system:

```
Unknown microcontroller  ==| connector |==+== PIC 12F509 with internal oscillator
                                          |== 24C16WI 2k EEPROM
                                          \== Logic analyzer
```

The first communication with the device is to send a write request to address 0x49, but when I attempt to do the same, I do not receive a response.  There are obvious timing differences in my request versus theirs, but I am not sure if they are significant.  Communication with the 24C16WI is successful, but I can get no response from the PIC.

Working request (baud rate 36kHz) ([Saleae capture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnLqHRLHy7i2hds--qxlO8G6kOfOqA)):
[image: I2C communication from working system]

My request (baud rate 31kHz) ([Saleae capture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnLqHRLHy7i2hds8rSqSFM79newS3Q)):
[image: My request]

Assuming that the difference does not rely upon a signal other than the I<sup>2</sup>C lines, are the timing differences in the signal significant?  If they are significant, how can I generate the required timing using an Atmel SAMD21J18?

What am I missing?

Comment: As a quick sanity check, hook a scope to the logic lines and make sure the levels are correct (or put the saleae into analog mode, if you have one that can do it). I've been bitten by a logic analyzer showing transitions that didn't actually meet the required specs.

Comment: **Master (CLK provider) is easy but slave  not !** 36 khz required 1Mhz divider for tracing what happened ?

Comment: In the working capture, the timing of the edges is horrible, but that might be a problem with the bus. This really requires an oscilloscope trace.

Comment: You're bit-banging an I2C slave inside PIC12F509? Perhaps you should look at its code. Have you tried an I2C-approved bus-clearing SCL/SDA sequence? Could also be a power-up hang.

Comment: I will get a scope hooked up to it shortly.  @glen_geek, I read through the slave device's (PIC12F509) datasheet but did not see a hardware I2C implementation.  I can only assume they are bit-banging.  I have not tried to dump the code, but I am guessing they have the code-protect fuse set.  The PIC12F509 is part of a third-party device, so I do not have access to original source code.

Comment: @dsgdfg, I don't understand.  I am acting as bus master to the third-party device's PIC12F509.  The measured frequencies are just by measuring the SCL period on the logic analyzer.

Comment: You're I2C'ing a bit faster than the successful transaction - perhaps the bit-bang 12F509 I2C code can't keep up. Did you try a transaction a little slower?

Comment: @glen_geek, my SCL is toggling slower than the working transaction.  I do note that there is a longer delay in the start sequence, but I am unsure how to produce that with the Atmel ASF I2C driver.

Comment: @mbrig, Low is 0v, high is 3.36v, 3.7Vdd.  No obvious noise during steady periods, 600ns rise time, 120ns fall time, ringing is ~1Vpp for 100ns.

Comment: Slave aren't easy mean, need 2 edge(Rise,Fall) detector and internal timer for received correct data. We talking about edge based communication so can't handle data if got a long period on edge detection. Merge all my comments and [check this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Summary:*** I suspect that the new I<sup>2</sup>C timing is not close enough to the original, and at least one "abnormal" I<sup>2</sup>C sequence is shown on the "working trace", which may be difficult for you to reproduce.

***Details:***

> Assuming that the difference does not rely upon a signal other than the I<sup>2</sup>C lines
>   [...]
>   What am I missing?

The logic analyser captures are very helpful, thanks. Along with the other info, I think we have a good "suspect".

> There are obvious timing differences in my request versus theirs, but I am not sure if they are significant.

I bet the timing differences *are* significant, especially since:

> Communication with the 24C16WI is successful

So using your own I<sup>2</sup>C Master, you can communicate with the standard I<sup>2</sup>C device (that EEPROM). As you said, the problem is trying to get a response from the PIC, and as you pointed out in a later comment, that PIC does not have a built-in I2C module:

> I read through the slave device's (PIC12F509) datasheet but did not see a hardware I2C implementation. I can only assume they are bit-banging.

Yes! I've seen other PIC devices (without an internal I<sup>2</sup>C module) programmed as I<sup>2</sup>C Slaves, which had significant timing restrictions on their I<sup>2</sup>C behaviour.

> I do note that there is a longer delay in the start sequence

Exactly. I haven't measured using the Saleae software, but "by eye" there is approximately 0.8 ms delay between the I<sup>2</sup>C Start condition and the first toggle of the SCL signal on the *working* trace, and no such delay on the *failing* trace.

That delay is not typical I<sup>2</sup>C behaviour, but I suspect it is necessary for the (unknown) PIC firmware to recognise the I<sup>2</sup>C Start condition (e.g. perhaps it has to wake from sleep, using the PIC GPIO "wake on change" feature, when the SDA signal changes as part of the I<sup>2</sup>C Start condition).

If I was in your situation, I would start with a hypothesis that *all* of the original I<sup>2</sup>C timing is important (not only the SCL clock speed, where you are already similar to the original speed) and try to duplicate the original timing **and behaviour** *completely*. After all, that original sequence *does work* :-)

There are other unusual parts to the "working" I<sup>2</sup>C transaction:

- In the address byte, there seems to be a small delay between the clock for bit 8 and the clock for the (9th) ACK/NACK bit. Again, that delay (which doesn't exist in your "failing" trace) might be required by the PIC firmware.
- In the next byte, I see only 8 clock pulses not the expected 9 pulses, which explains the Saleae software's comment about "Missing ACK/NACK". Again, this (abnormal) I<sup>2</sup>C behaviour might be required to match the expectations of the PIC firmware, but is likely to be difficult or impossible to reproduce, using "normal" I<sup>2</sup>C driver / library code, as this would typically generate all 9 normal clock pulses.

> I am unsure how to produce that with the Atmel ASF I2C driver.

I haven't used that driver. You can investigate whether you can insert a delay after sending the I<sup>2</sup>C Start condition, before sending the device address. That is separate from the "Missing ACK/NACK" clock pulse (which *might* need to be missing!) when the Master transmitted the second byte in the "working trace".

Therefore you may be unable to use that driver "as is", and instead may need to write your own low-level ("driver") code, which gives you more control. If all else fails to give you the necessary amount of timing and clock pulse control, you might need to bit-bang the Master's SDA and SCL signals yourself for some or all of the I<sup>2</sup>C protocol sequences you need.

Comment: I think you are on to something, here.  Adding a delay between the start condition and the first data bit by switching to a software I2C implementation got the PIC to acknowledge the address byte.  I think that the interface may be mislabeled as I2C :)  The missing ack on byte 2 is especially interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the address 0X49?

I Found this data on the 24C16 implying the base address is 0x50.  Be careful about the 7-bit or 8-bit representation of the address.

The timing of the "working request" looks bad.  You need to have setup time ahead of the positive edge of the clock.

You request is better formed but has the wrong address.

[image]

Comment: Kevin, I am trying to communicate with the PIC, not with the 24C16.  I can communicate with the 24C16 successfully on address 0x50.

Comment: Sorry - my error.  Even so the timing looks bad on the working request.  The data is changing at the same time as the positive edge of the clock - that is not legal I2C. Where is the Start transition?

Comment: That does look a bit close for comfort.  Zooming in [shows data coming in about 1 μs before clock rising](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BtQb.png).